Bootstrap-5 justify-content not adding space between or anything justify
Trying to space out 3 images with space around or space between depending on what I like. For some reason, the images stay stuck together in the center instead of justify-content-around. I tried taking and changing the img width thinking that maybe you couldn't justify a img-fluid.
 <div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end my-5">
    <div class="border border-2 px-2">
      <img class="img-fluid px-4" src="girl.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="border border-2 px-2">
      <img class="img-fluid px-4" src="girl.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="border border-2 px-2">
      <img class="img-fluid px-4" src="girl.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 


Have a look at what I get with your code: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/XWLBeQq Is that what you want? All I did was change "justify-content-end" to "justify-content-around". If not, then I'm not sure what your problem is?

it must be something going on with the img itself. I copied and pasted the exact code from your codepen with your img and it worked. If I replace your img with my img it goes back to doing the exact same thing  as before. Really weird.

Possibly, but then I can't tell what that thing it did before is. All I know is that your "images stay stuck together in the center", but that's not very clear. Do they actually overlap?

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container my-5">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly  border p-3">
              <div class="">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607798748738-b15c40d33d57?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" width="300px"  alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607798748738-b15c40d33d57?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" width="300px" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <img class="img-fluid " src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607798748738-b15c40d33d57?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" width="300px" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
    </div>


When we use justify-content:space-between then the first item is aligned with the start of the container, and the last item is aligned with the end of the container.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You need to use justify-content-between to add space between the images. If the images size is big and space doesn't appear then try to adjust width and height of each image. Also try to use Bootstrap class gap i.e., gap-3.
Read more about Flex here.
